# Webp Image not generating when azure CDN enabled

Tags: jss, azure, cdn, dianoga

With `Dianoga.WebP.config` enabled, I replaced `JSS` media handler in `web.config`:
with custom one:

```
using MediaRequestHandler = Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media.MediaRequestHandler;

public class JSSWebPMediaHandler : MediaRequestHandler
{
    protected override bool DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context, MediaRequest request, Media media)
    {
        if (context?.Request.AcceptTypes != null && context.Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("image/webp"))
        {
            request.Options.CustomOptions["extension"] = "webp";
        }
        return base.DoProcessRequest(context, request, media);
    }
},
```

**Environment description**
Scaled environment

**What configs you have enabled**

```
Dianoga.DisableForSites.config,
Dianoga.Jpeg.config,
Dianoga.Png.config,
Dianoga.WebP.CDN.config ,
Dianoga.WebP.config,
Dianoga.Svg.configDianoga.Svg.config,
Dianoga.Strategy.GetMediaStreamSync.config
```

**What you expected to see, versus what you actually saw**
expected result: Images should convert to webp format
Actual result: Images are coming in the same png and jpg format

In a standalone environment without CDN the images are converting to webp images but in a scaled environment with Azure CDN images are not converting

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Azure CDN (Microsoft) or Azure Front Door Classic with Azure CDN (Microsoft), `Accept` header is not passed to the Origin server. Dianoga needs `Accept` header to understand whether it supports nextgen image formats or not.

If the pages are not routed via Azure CDN, then `Accept` header will be passed to the origin server only for the page requests. Dianoga and Sitecore will generate the media link with Extension query param `extension=webp,{other image formats}`. If this query param is available, then Dianoga will be able to generate the `webp` format without reading the `Accept` header of media request.

**Option 1**: Upgrade Azure CDN to Verizon Premium (costly) and it passes the header back to Origin server and Dianoga will be able to optimize and send the `webp` Images.

**Option 2**: If you have a rule engine in your CDN, create a rule to send the Accept header in a different header name and use that header name in Dianoga to generate the `webp` format. This needs a rule engine before the requests hit the Azure CDN.
[Option to enable webp format using Azure CDN](https://www.nehemiahj.com/2022/08/sitecore-dianoga-with-azure-cdn.html)

Answer (score 0):

have you checked `Dianoga` documentation here: https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga#optimization-strategies?

On which version of `Dianoga` you are? It seems you need to enable `Dianoga.NextGenFormats.CDN.config`:

If you run `Sitecore` under CDN: review and enable
`Dianoga.NextGenFormats.CDN.config.disabled`. It will add
`?extension= <list of supported extensions>` query parameter to all
images present on your pages.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different ways to get this to work correctly with a CDN:

1. Through the `Accept` header. Based on your question it seems like this is the approach you are trying to use. You will have to configure your CDN to properly handle the `Accept` header. I'm not familiar with Azure CDN but I had to configure my CDN to include this header in the cache key.
2. Through the `extension=webp` query string, this is also one of the key features which `Dianoga.WebP.CDN.config` adds. However your custom `MediaRequestHandler` does not check this querystring. If this is your approach you will have to update your code in `JSSWebPMediaHandler`. You can use the Dianoga [MediaRequestHandler](https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga/blob/master/src/Dianoga/NextGenFormats/MediaRequestHandler.cs) as an example and see what [this](https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga/blob/28fa1580b211f564ef71d0e36668a4363309a283/src/Dianoga/NextGenFormats/MediaRequestHandler.cs#L10) method call does.